# program structure callback

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there

i have a basic question about program structure. I want to write a node that calls the laser_assembler service and publishes those scans witch have been taken during one tilt motion of my servo motor. To do so i thought of subscribing to the motor state msg the motor service publishes.
How would you structure this node. Would you bind all the objects that are needed (service client, publisher ...) to the callback? Or would you write a class for this (witch would be basically my whole node). Or is it ok to have a couple of global variables?

thanks
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194333/program-structure-callback/) by [AlexKolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20130/alexkolb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any of those approaches will work.

As your program gets bigger and more complicated, having a class will probably be the most maintainable.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ahendrix is absolutely right.

Object Oriented Programming should be the weapon of choice.

Always remember [the side effect of global variables.](http://hotmeme.net/media/i/6/6/oIP-every-time-you-create-a-global-variable-god-kills-a-kitten.jpg)

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1